# prevent children from inheriting translateZ property

Tags: html, css, transform

I am trying to create a 3d cube effect using css3. I am using translateZ property to create the 3d cube environment when I use translateZ on parent div the child div automatically inherits the property. I have tried to use **transform: none** and the tried to give negative transform but of no use. Here is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcobbvcL/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="box-big">
    <div class="box">
        <h1>ABCD</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    body{
    perspective: 1000px; 
}
.box-big{
    transform-style: perserve-3D;
}
.box{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #FF0000;
    transform: translateZ(400px);
}
h1{
    font-color: white;
    line-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateZ(-400px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the children of the parent are going to be rendered according to the parent, so what you are asking is not possible. You would have to re-transform it to what you want, or probably your best bet is to use some "layering" technique (such as position: absolute or negative margins) so that the h1 can be outside of the .box element, but still appear "on top" of the .box element.

Here's a working example:

Modified HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box-big">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>ABCD</h1>
</div>
```

Modified CSS:

```
body{
    perspective: 1000px; 
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.box-big {
    transform-style: preserve-3D;
}
.box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #FF0000;
    transform: translateZ(300px);
    z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 255555;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kcobbvcL/4/

As a side note, your fiddle css has some typos.  Be sure to use a good IDE or a browser tool to watch for illegal / invalid css.

Answer (score 0):

every cube has 6 sides, so u should use 6 div s. As we want to move the whole cube we should include those 6 div s in one div (div#cube).

first, you should create the cube using css, as the example below, then you translate or rotate the cube, using transform in div#cube.

```css
   .container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

#cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#cube figure {
  width: 196px;
  height: 196px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#cube .front  { transform: rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 100px ); }
#cube .back   { transform: rotateX( 180deg ) translateZ( 100px ); }
#cube .right  { transform: rotateY(  90deg ) translateZ( 100px ); }
#cube .left   { transform: rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 100px ); }
#cube .top    { transform: rotateX(  90deg ) translateZ( 100px ); }
#cube .bottom { transform: rotateX( -90deg ) translateZ( 100px ); }

#cube{
transition: all 1s;
}
#cube:hover{
transform: rotateY( -20deg );
/*transform: translateZ( -100px );*/
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div id="cube">
    <figure class="front">1</figure>
    <figure class="back">2</figure>
    <figure class="right">3</figure>
    <figure class="left">4</figure>
    <figure class="top">5</figure>
    <figure class="bottom">6</figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: But if you notice the text in the cubes are being scaled and get that blurred thing that is what I want to get rid of.